# Sublime Text - Build and run C program

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

So I want to make the 'Run' variant build and run the target file, not just build it. In Linux I could just do `&& ./$file` or w/e but how can I do this in Windows?

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],

    "variants": [

        {   
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just doing the following?

```json
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],

    "variants": [

        {   
            "cmd": ["gcc", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run"
        }
    ]
}
```

`&&` works the same way on the Windows `cmd` command line as it does in Unix/Linux shells. Unfortunately, if you're just reading out the results of your build command in the bottom pane of Sublime, `&&` doesn't seem to work, at least on the latest build of ST3 on Win8. So, you can just fall back to a good old batch file:

```bat
@echo off
gcc -o %1 %2
%1
```

Save this someplace in your `PATH` as `buildandrun.bat`. Next, create a new build system:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["buildandrun.bat", "$file_base_name", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.c"
}
```

and save it as `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\buildandrun.sublime-build`. Select your source file in Sublime, go to `Tools -> Build System` and select `buildandrun` down at the bottom, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about `&&` working on Windows too! However, this launches a cmd prompt which I can live with, but it would be nice to launch it via sublime's built in CLI seeing as I use it for other builds.

Comment: @Jazcash check out my edit above. It involves building a quick batch file, but in the end all errors and output will display in the Sublime build pane at the bottom of the window.

Comment: This is really awesome, thank you so much! Nice thinking with the batch file.